# MS Access Group Summary

Tags: ms-access

I'm fairly new to Access, and I have a database (didn't make it, inherited it and don't currently have access to the author or full documentation) that contains a bunch of financial information for the company I'm interning at, and I'm running into a strange error with, well, group summaries in a report. Allow me to illustrate (format visible but actual information obscured):

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rpb9L.png) is the information displayed correctly, as happens sometimes (the actual detail group is two layers below what's currently visible). The green is where the summary is correct for where it *should be.* The red is where the summary is giving the correct values for the second Project Responsibility row, specifically.

Then I clicked Hide Detail in the first Project Responsibility row which, as far as I can tell, runs only an embedded macro that makes things visible or not and changes the button's caption (it's the only thing listed under Event in Properties), then clicked it again (didn't actually need to to induce the error, but I wanted the report to look as similar as possible). The report now displayed [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBjoG.png), colours symbolizing exactly what they did before.

The design view versions of those cells are just =Sum([the column's variable displayed]), except for the % column which is =Avg. They themselves have no event handling Properties is showing me.

The error is reproducible, but not exactly consistently: sometimes the summary starts out correct, sometimes it *becomes* correct after fiddling with the various Show/Hide Detail buttons, sometimes it's the first time I've opened that report after starting Access and sometimes not. The only constant is that hitting a Show/Hide Detail button when it's correct makes it cease to be.

Anyone know anything about what might be causing this? If not, could you explain what further details might be helpful in narrowing it down so I can provide as much as I can?

Comment: Do your company a favor and remind them that Access isn't a good place for such financial calculations.  If this is desk drawer software, you'd serve them better by figuring out how to put this under source control and move it to a real platform.

Comment: That's the plan. They have me supporting this until that's done, though.

Comment: Specifically are the fields that are incorrect calculated fields? Are they refreshed upon hiding/unhiding?

Comment: Yes, the fields that are incorrect are calculated. Like I said, they're simply =Sum([the column's variable]), or in one case =Avg. And I'm not certain. The macro only toggles their Visible property. I don't _think_ that refreshes them (says a quick and not quite clear Google check, I'm a novice here), and there's definitely nothing explicitly doing anything like that.